# getting domain age using preg match all

Tags: php, regex

I would like to calculate the domain age of a website
the content is from http://who.godaddy.com/whoisverify.aspx

here are some result that i found from godaddy.

```
Created on: 26-Dec-03
Record created on 2009-01-15.
Creation date: 27 Oct 2006 19:43:06
Created on..............: 1997-03-28
```

I would like to get the year and subtract it to the current year to get the domain age.
but there are at least 4 creation date format how could i check them all using preg_match_all to get the year domain age?

Please help me guys,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a line that has 'creat' on it then capture everything from the first digit to the new line character (or .)

Might have to change the `(?:\n|\.)` though based on the actual text

```
$str =  <<<END
Created on: 26-Dec-03
Record created on 2009-01-15.
Creation date: 27 Oct 2006 19:43:06
Created on..............: 1997-03-28

END;

preg_match_all( '~creat.*?(\d.*?)(?:\n|\.)~i', $str, $matches );

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: now I will only have to get the 4 digit number and subtract it to the current year to get the domain age. the only problem is if the year is 2 digit **97**

Comment: use strtotime on it and do the math with the result

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create on catch-all regex pattern I would look for a line that has `creat` on it (case insensitive) then search it for a variety of date formats.